# Netlogo: is ´map´ limited to two lists?

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

When I try the following command on NL 6.1.1:

```
(map + [1 2 3] [2 4 6] [7 8 9])
```

I get `[3 6 9]`as a result instead of `[10 14 18]`, which means that only the first two lists are considered in the sum.

Anyone knows how to correct this and get all three lists to be considered ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per [the documentation in the NetLogo dictionary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map), the `map` reporter does support multiple lists, but `map` expects the provided anonymous reporter to take a number of arguments equal to the number of lists you provide.  In your case you cannot use the `+` shortcut since `+` takes 2 arguments, and we have 3 lists.

So instead you can do this:

```
(map [ [a b c] -> a + b + c ] [1 2 3] [2 4 6] [7 8 9])
```

If you need to handle adding an arbitrary number of lists (as in a list variable that could have 2, 3, 4, or more lists inside of it depending on your program), you can try this out using [the `reduce` reporter](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#reduce):

```
set vals [[1 2 3] [2 4 6] [7 8 9] [10 11 12]]
reduce [ [a b] -> (map + a b) ] vals
```

Comment: Thanks @Jasper, that is exactly what I was trying to get at, since I have a variable-length list of 3-dimensional vectors. I don't entirely understand the syntax but I see it works. I will study it a bit more. Cheers!

Comment: Glad I included the second one!  One note is that the `reduce` will not work with length 0 lists, so you'll need to handle that case separately:  `ifelse-value length vals = 0 [0] [reduce [ [a b] -> (map + a b) ] vals]`